# json returns [object Object] instead of actual data

Tags: json

I have refered many questions on stack overflow and on other sites for the solution. But everywhere I got incomplete answer. some answer says log the json data to console. So I tried it and there I get the json object correctly. But when I add it to HTML or alert it says [object Object].

There are many duplicates of this question but still I dont understand what the problem is?
Here is my code so far

```
$(document).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/members/ListOfAllOppositeTypeUsersWithTheirRespectiveData?LoggedInUserOppositeType=2",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                //var strJson = JSON.stringify(json);
                $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                    $('#AllowedFriends').append($('<option value="'+ key + '">' + value + '</option>'));
                });

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("F");
            }
        });
    });
```

**edit :**

The values that I get in the console :

```
0: Object
MemberID: 1
Name: "Cipla"

1: Object
MemberID: 2
Name: "Himalaya"
```

Comment: A JSON object IS an object. Calling $.each() on a string isn't going to work. Post an example of the object you get back, and we can help you access it.

Comment: should I post the values that I get in Console.log?

Comment: Anything that shows the actual response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
$.each(json, function (index, obj) {
    $('#AllowedFriends').append($('<option value="'+ obj.MemberId + '">' + obj.Name + '</option>'));
});
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the response is an array, not an object containing an array. In your developer console, an array response will be enclosed in brackets []. An object response will be enclosed in braces {}.

Comment: So what you have there is an ARRAY of OBJECTS. $.each() iterates over the array, passing the index and array element to the supplied function. In your case, that array element is an object.

Answer (score 0):

An object can contain actual data, what is the problem? I suggest you take a look at the network calls from your browser using the developer console or Firebug to see what object is received. Then jQuery parses the string into an object so you can use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(eval('('+json+')'));`